# Discord py - reaction role

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

** want to make reaction role which if user react message on specific channel will get role
but it doesn't work**

```
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(member):
  ChannelID = 932268491556405268
  role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=941124409341648957)
  if member.message.channel.id != ChannelID:
    return
  if member.emoji == "1️⃣":
    await member.add_roles(role, reason=None, atomic=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `payload` object from [`on_raw_reaction_add`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html?highlight=on_raw_reaction_add#discord.on_raw_reaction_add) to do what you want

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):  # Requires Intents.reactions
    channel = client.get_channel(...)
    guild = client.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
    role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=...)

    if str(payload.emoji) == "1️⃣":
        await payload.member.add_roles(role, atomic=True)
        await channel.send(...)
```